# Compute TF-IDF word score with relevant and random corpus

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, tf-idf, nlp

Given a corpus of relevant documents (CORPUS) and a corpus of random documents (ran_CORPUS) I want to compute TF-IDF scores for all words in CORPUS, using ran_CORPUS as a base line. In my project, the ran_CORPUS has approximately 10 times as many documents as CORPUS.

```
CORPUS = ['this is a relevant document',
          'this one is a relevant text too']
ran_CORPUS = ['the sky is blue',
              'my cat has a furry tail']
```

My plan is to normalize the documents, make all documents in CORPUS to one document (CORPUS being now a list with one long string element). To CORPUS I append all ran_CORPUS documents. Using `sklearn's TfidfTransformer` I then would compute the TF-IDF matrix for the corpus (consisting now of CORPUS and ran_CORPUS). And finally select the first row of that CORPUS to get the TF-IDF scores for my initial relevant CORPUS.

Does anybody know whether this approach could work and if there is a simple way to code it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "whether this approach could work", I presume you mean does merging all the relevant documents into one and vectorising present a valid model. I would guess it depends what you are going to try to do with that model.

I'm not much of a mathematician, but I imagine that this is like averaging the scores for all your documents into one vector space, so you have lost some of the shape of the space the original vector space occupied by the individual relevant documents. So you have tried to make a "master" or "prototype" document which is mean to represent a topic?

If you are then going to do something like similarity matching with test documents, or classification by distance comparison then you may have lost some of the subtlety of the original documents' vectorisation. There may be more facets to the overall topic than the averages represent.

More specifically, imagine your original "relevant corpus" has two clusters of documents because there are actually two main sub-topics represented by different groups of important features. Later while doing classification, test documents could match either of those clusters individually - again because they are close to one of the two sub-topics. By averaging the whole "relevant corpus" in this case you would end up with a single document that was half-way between both of these clusters, but not accurately representing either. Therefore the test presentations might not match at all - depending on the classification technique.

I think it's hard to say without trialling it on proper specific corpuses.

Regardless of the validity, below is how it could be implemented.

Note you can also use the TfidfVectorizer to combine the vectorising and Tfidf'ing steps in one. The results are not always the exactly same, but they are in this case.

Also, you say normalise the documents - typically you might normalise the a vector representation before feeding into a classification algorithm which requires a normalised distribution (like SVM). However I think TFIDF naturally normalises so it doesn't appear to have any further effect (I may be wrong here).

```
import logging
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer

CORPUS = ['this is a relevant document',
          'this one is a relevant text too']
ran_CORPUS = ['the sky is blue',
              'my cat has a furry tail']

doc_CORPUS = ' '.join([str(x) for x in CORPUS])
ran_CORPUS.append(doc_CORPUS)

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(ran_CORPUS)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_counts)

logging.debug("\nCount + TdidfTransform \n%s" % X_tfidf.toarray())

# or do it in one pass with TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(ran_CORPUS)

logging.debug("\nTdidfVectoriser \n%s" % X_tfidf.toarray())

# normalising doesn't achieve much as tfidf is already normalised.
normalizer = preprocessing.Normalizer() 
X_tfidf = normalizer.transform(X_tfidf)
logging.debug("\nNormalised:\n%s" % X_tfidf.toarray())


Count + TdidfTransform 
[[0.52863461 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.40204024
  0.         0.         0.         0.52863461 0.         0.
  0.52863461 0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.4472136  0.         0.4472136  0.4472136  0.
  0.4472136  0.         0.         0.         0.4472136  0.
  0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.2643173  0.         0.         0.40204024
  0.         0.2643173  0.52863461 0.         0.         0.2643173
  0.         0.52863461 0.2643173 ]]

TdidfVectoriser 
[[0.52863461 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.40204024
  0.         0.         0.         0.52863461 0.         0.
  0.52863461 0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.4472136  0.         0.4472136  0.4472136  0.
  0.4472136  0.         0.         0.         0.4472136  0.
  0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.2643173  0.         0.         0.40204024
  0.         0.2643173  0.52863461 0.         0.         0.2643173
  0.         0.52863461 0.2643173 ]]

Normalised:
[[0.52863461 0.         0.         0.         0.         0.40204024
  0.         0.         0.         0.52863461 0.         0.
  0.52863461 0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.4472136  0.         0.4472136  0.4472136  0.
  0.4472136  0.         0.         0.         0.4472136  0.
  0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.2643173  0.         0.         0.40204024
  0.         0.2643173  0.52863461 0.         0.         0.2643173
  0.         0.52863461 0.2643173 ]]
```